# What kind of exercises should I do to develop more endurance for sally up pushup challenge?

Tags: push-ups, endurance

From time to time I like to do the "Bring Sally Up" pushup challenge. I usually put [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41N6bKO-NVI) on, so that I can track how much I last.

I am able to do sets of 30-60 pushups, depending on the day, but I find that I'm not able to last more than about 2:40 of this challenge.

What kind of exercises should I do, in order to be able to improve my time?

Answer (score 1):

First you need proper technique. Elbows close to body, forearms still, back stretched, blade-bones proper position... Kelly Starrett did some [videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=kelly%20starrett%20push%20up) on that.

According to muscles - when I'm failing, I know where the pain is located. From that, usually I know what to train. If I have to bet - deltoids, upper chest, triceps. But if someone argue about abs - I agree as well.